# Asp.Net MVC Javascript Create Barcode Problem

Tags: javascript, barcode

In the example where I shared the code, I list the data in my model.
I also generate barcode image with javascript from the barcode number that comes with the model.
However, only the first result is producing a barcode image. The barcode image of other lines is empty.
How do I make a change in Javascript?

```html
@using BarcodeViewer.Models
@using System.Collections.Generic

@model List<PrintModel>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HTML EAN13 Barcode</title>
    <script src="~/js/connectcode-javascript-ean13.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #barcode {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            line-height: normal;
            sans-serif;
            font-size: 12pt
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <table style="width:300px">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><b>Tarih</b> </td>
                    <td>@m.Tarih.ToShortDateString()</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Gönderen</b></td>
                    <td colspan="3">@m.Gonderen</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Alıcı<b></td>
                    <td colspan="3">@m.Alici</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>İl</b></td>
                    <td>@m.City</td>
                    <td><b>İlçe</b></td>
                    <td>@m.Town</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Miktar</b></td>
                    <td>@m.Quantity</td>
                    <td><b>Birim</b></td>
                    <td>@m.Birim</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Stok Adı:</b></td>
                    <td colspan="3">@m.StokAdi</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div id="barcodecontainer" style="width:3in; align-content:flex-start" >
                <div id="barcode">@m.Barcode</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    }
  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* <![CDATA[ */
        function get_object(id) {
            var object = null;
            if (document.layers) {
                object = document.layers[id];
            } else if (document.all) {
                object = document.all[id];
            } else if (document.getElementById) {
                object = document.getElementById(id);
            }
            return object;
                   
        }
        get_object("barcode").innerHTML = DrawHTMLBarcode_EAN13(get_object("barcode").innerHTML, "yes", "in", 0, 2.5, 1, "bottom", "center", "", "black", "white");
        /* ]]> */

    </script>           
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using an `id` attribute for multiple elements. `id` tags must be unique within the DOM. `getElementById` will only return the first element with given `id`.

Try using a `class` instead of an `id` and update your javascript code to "run for each element instance of class".

**Don't use id attribute inside that loop. (id="barcodecontainer", id="barcode")**

```
<div class="barcode"></div>
```

And js:

```
var barcodeElements = document.getElementsByClassName("barcode");

for(var i = 0; i < barcodeElements.length; i++) {
    barcodeElements[i].innerHTML = DrawHTMLBarcode_EAN13(barcodeElements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

> But you better use **jQuery** instead of this js code.

**Lib for jQuery:** https://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html

> Here is usage for your code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="barcode" data-code="@m.Barcode"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".barcode").each(function(){
    $(this).barcode($(this).attr('data-code'), "ean13");
});
```

Comment: Excellent.Thank you.